# Defining interface multiple times on inherited class

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

I essentially define `IFoo` twice in the Inherited class. Does that cause some unforeseen consequences?

```
interface IFoo {
   ...
}

interface IBar : IFoo {
   ...
}

class Base : IFoo {
   ...
}

class Derived : Base, IBar {
   ...
}
```

The reason I want to make `IBar` inherit from `IFoo` is so I can work on `Derived` as it was `IFoo` without having to cast it.

```
if (Derived is IBar)
   // Do work
```

If it doesn't inherit I have to cast it. Which makes use more complicated, and users of the class might not understand that `IBar` just is a specialization of `IFoo`.

```
if (Derived is IBar)
   Derived as IFoo
   // Do work
```

Is this bad practice? What other solutions are there to this problem?

Comment: Why do you want to do `if (Derived is IBar) Derived as IFoo`?  Why not `if (Derived is IFoo)` instead?

Comment: Because IBar is a marker interface which tells me that `Derived` is of a specific type. This way I can keep all IFoo in a collection and work with them all. Should I need to only "do work" on IBar types I can do .OfType<IBar>.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will not cause any unforeseen circumstances in code terms. It's just redundant.

As for this code:

```
if (Derived is IBar)
   Derived as IFoo
```

That's completely unnecessary since `Derived` *is* an `IFoo`, given your declarations - so don't do that!

Note that even if `IBar` doesn't derive from `IFoo`, you still don't need `Derived as IFoo`. Given:

```
interface IFoo {}

interface IBar {}

class Base : IFoo {}

class Derived : Base, IBar 
{
}
```

Then this compiles ok:

```
var derived = new Derived();

IBar bar = derived; // Fine.
IFoo foo = derived; // Also fine.
```

Comment: `Derived as IFoo` was an example of what I had to do if `IBar` didn't derive from `IFoo`

Comment: @Snæbjørn But that's not true - even if `IBar` doesn't derive from `IFoo`,  `Base` already does so you don't need `Derived as IFoo`. See my updated answer.

Comment: Ah yes, that's correct. I'm starting to realize I didn't explain the problem correctly :(. Your suggestion is how I normally would do, and probably is how I should do. This should probably be another post, but here goes. I'm storing both Base and Derived in a `List<IFoo>`. I want to extract all `IBar`s from the list. This I do using `list.OfType<Ibar>` problem is I can't store that list in a `List<IFoo>` without using `.Cast<IFoo>` which is unintuitive. I'm starting to doubt my design :)

Comment: @Snæbjørn Aye, I think it's worth making a new question with more of those sorts of details in it.

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly define an implementation for an `Interface` and so distinguish in behavior

```
class Derived : Base, IBar {

    void IBar.Method(){

    }

    void Base.Method() {

    }
}
```

Apart from that, you can do that, but it is redundant and might cause confusion. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Comment: is that even legal syntax?

Comment: I was wrong about `override`, the MSDN-article says that you can do that. VS even offers this feature

Comment: I think the methods should be `private` then you are implementing an interface like that

Comment: Method-declarations in an `interface` are all implicitly `public` and `abstract`, so why declare them as `private`?

Comment: only the interface method `IBar.Method` need to be private. look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: @JensKloster I see what you did :)

Comment: when using explicit implementation, you don't specify the accessibility modifier; that should be just `void IBar.Method() {...}`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you have one hierarchy of interfaces and one hierarchy of classes mirroring each other. Each class implements the corresponding interface by inheriting from it's base class and implementing the additional members needed.

This is just fine and I do it the same way. I don't know any better way to do this - this **is** a good approach.

I think IBar should extend IFoo just like your main suggestion, otherwise consumers would need to cast a lot. Also, **since you consider IBar a specialization** of IFoo, also **make it a specialization** in the code, so make it extend IFoo.